# Is it possible that using IDENT_CURRENT is duplicating the foreign key in the child table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have written a procedure which inserts data into two tables in one proceure parent and child.

If a record is inserted into the parent table then it's primary key should be inserted as a foreign key in the second.

So what I did is

```
            Declare @HeaderID int
            Set @HeaderID= IDENT_CURRENT('EQ') --Latest ID
```

So multiple people are connected to the same database and using this procedure.

Now, what my concern is that the PRIMARY KEY would not be duplicated? right? If a user A inserts data into the Parent table and e.g. ID=1 is generated then for the user B who also inserts record will get ID=2 or something else. right?

My friend says that it should be SCOPE_IDENTITY but I don't agree because that would record a primary key for any table.

Comment: You can use the [OUTPUT clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) instead to retrieve only the ID inserted in the last INSERT statement, eg `INSERT INTO ... OUTPUT @inserted.id INTO ...`

Comment: yeah but are there any negative sides to using IDENT_CURRENT in my situation

Comment: Yes there are downsides, Aaron Bertrand has written about them here - [For the last time, NO, you can't trust IDENT_CURRENT()](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/01/t-sql-queries/ident-current). In summary, you can't trust the value, so don't use it. Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` for a single value, or `OUTPUT` for multiple.

Comment: "that would record a primary key for any table." - but only within the current scope - i.e. it's code that *one* session is running, and not subject to anything happening in nested scopes, such as triggers. You should know exactly which tables your own, small, section of code is interacting with and therefore which table `SCOPE_IDENTITY` will be retrieving a value for.

Answer (score 0):

IDENT_CURRENT returns the last identity value generated for a specific table in any session and any scope.

@@IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session, across all scopes.

SCOPE_IDENTITY returns the last identity value generated for any table in the current session and the current scope.

Use caution when using IDENT_CURRENT to predict the next generated identity value. The actual generated value may be different from IDENT_CURRENT plus IDENT_INCR because of insertions performed by other sessions.

the better option is to use SCOPE_IDENTITY()

ref [IDENT_CURRENT (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/ident-current-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)